# Attempting to break up a list into a list of list, but master list keeps unintentionally updating

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of apartment listings and their price. The data looks roughly like this:

```
['$2,973', '14 mo', '0 Bed', '/', '1 Bath', '533 sq.ft.', '/', 'Floor 6', 'Available 4/25/2020', 'Special Offer', '$3,973', '11 mo', '1 Bed', '/', '1 Bath', '533 sq.ft.', '/', 'Floor 6', 'Available 4/12/2020', 'Special Offer']
```

I want to break out these 2 apartment lists into a list of lists with the "$" as the indicator for a new list. I wrote this code, but for some reason, my master "list" variable keeps getting updated even when going through the else statement. Can you help me figure out why/what is going on?

```
list = []
tmp_list = []

for string in soup.stripped_strings:
    if '$' in string:
        print(tmp_list)
        list.append(tmp_list)
        print(list)
        tmp_list.clear()
        tmp_list.append(string)
        print('if')
        print(tmp_list)
        print(list)
    else:

        tmp_list.append(string)
        print('string', string)
        print('else')
        print(tmp_list)
        print(list)
```

my results from the print statements -- for whatever reason, the tmp_list and list keep getting updated even through the else statement

```
[]
[[]]
if
['$2,973']
[['$2,973']]
string 14 mo
else
['$2,973', '14 mo']
[['$2,973', '14 mo']]
string 0 Bed
else
['$2,973', '14 mo', '0 Bed']
[['$2,973', '14 mo', '0 Bed']]
```

Comment: just to confirm. fo you want the solution as this. ```[['$2,973', '14 mo', '0 Bed', '/', '1 Bath', '533 sq.ft.', '/', 'Floor 6', 'Available 4/25/2020', 'Special Offer'], ['$3,973', '11 mo', '1 Bed', '/', '1 Bath', '533 sq.ft.', '/', 'Floor 6', 'Available 4/12/2020', 'Special Offer']]
```

Answer (score 1):

`list` is updated when you update `tmp_list` because `tmp_list` is inside of `list`.

Essentially, tmp_list will always be `[item1, item2, ...]` and `list` will always be `[tmp_list]` in your code.

Also, instead of clearing the `tmp_list`, you should assign a new list to it (`tmp_list = []`) because `clear()` will not change the list to a new one.

Essentially, change `tmp_list.clear()` to `tmp_list = []` to get a new list every time, and only append `tmp_list` to `list` if `len(tmp_list) > 0`:

Here's what it would look like without prints:

```
if len(tmp_list) > 0:
    list.append(tmp_list)
tmp_list = []
tmp_list.append(string)
```

And then you will need to append `tmp_list` to `list` after the for loop is over

Comment: Ah, I see that now. Thanks! Just tried this and it worked: list.append(tmp_list[:])

Comment: If you want `list` to have 2 lists in it, you need to use 3 lists.  The main list is holding 2 other lists for a total of 3 different lists

Comment: @DavidKang `tmp_list[:]` will also work since `[:]` will copy the list contents into a new list.